# java.lang.IllegalStateException when trying to play sound in background with service

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play an audio track in background so that it continues running when the user press the home button.

My approach is to use Service as it seems to be the most optimised way to accomplish such behavior.

My code is divided in an Activity and a Service file:

**AudioPlaybackActivity.java**

```
//....
Intent serviceIntent;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.audio_playback_activity);
try
{
    serviceIntent = new Intent(this, AudioPlaybackService.class);
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

  @Override
    public void onClick (View view)
    {
       switch (view.getId())
       {
           // ........
           case R.id.play:
           {
                try
                {
                 startService(serviceIntent); // Start the service when click on the play button
                }catch(Exception e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               break;
           }
       }
    }
```

**AudioPlaybackService.java**:

```
public class AudioPlaybackService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poi1);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        stopAudio();
        stopSelf(); // Stop the Service itself
    }
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0)
    {
        playAudio();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }


    public void playAudio()
    {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
    public void stopAudio()
    {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
           mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
```

The **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
//......... 
<service android:name="com.medigarage.audioguide.AudioPlaybackService"
        android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

Whenever I click the play button to launch the audio playback, the app crash. Here is the backtrace:

```
09-23 20:41:11.960 32753-32753/com.xxxxx.xxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxx.xxxxxx, PID: 32753
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.AudioPlaybackService@42851838 with Intent { cmp=com.xxxx.xxxxxx/.AudioPlaybackService }: java.lang.IllegalStateException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2872)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
  at com.xxxxx.xxxxxx.AudioPlaybackService.onStartCommand(AudioPlaybackService.java:35)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2855)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any thoughts why the service is not starting ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poi1);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

According to the [Android Docs for MediaPlayer.create()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int))

> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On
>   success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be
>   called again.

You should not be calling `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` after calling `MediaPlayer.create()`

Although if you do want to prepare the `MediaPlayer` asynchronously, you can set the data source directly instead of using the convenience `create()` method, like this:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.poi1));
```

Comment: Now I am getting the following compiling error: `cannot resolve method setDataSource(android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor`

Comment: Looks like that method was added in [API 24](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor)), so instead just turn the `AssetFileDescriptor` into a `FileDescriptor` using the method `getFileDescriptor()` like this `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.poi1).getFileDescriptor());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your service is actually starting but the media player is hung up on preparing.

When you play a file locally, don't use `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();`, creating the media player like you did automatically prepares the player. Just remove the `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();` line and it should work.

EDIT:

You can do it like you are doing it but without the prepareAsync() line, or alternatively like this:

1) Put the location of your raw audio source into a URI, like so:

```
Uri UriOfFile = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.my.package/raw/audioFileName");
```

2) And then this code to play the file:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), UriOfFile);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // or prepareAsync()
mediaPlayer.start();
```